# HandlerCallback<R, C = undefined> defintion

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Does anyone know what this means in TypeScript:

```
export interface HandlerCallback<R, C = undefined> {
  <R,C>(err?: JsonApiError, result?: R, count?: C): any
  <R>(err?: JsonApiError, result?: R): any
}
```

I have tried googling but I do not know the names of some the syntax, what it does, etc.  It makes it hard to ask a question with words like "thingy."

What would I build that matched this interface?

```
const something:HandlerCallback<WhatAmI> = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "thingy" is called [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and are basically used as a placeholder for a type that can be [infered](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) from function argument or specified manually like

```js
const something:HandlerCallback<string, number> = ???
```

so in that case every `R` is replaced by `string` and `C` by `number`, so it results in interface that looks like:

```
interface HandlerCallback {
  (err?: JsonApiError, result?: string, count?: number): any
  (err?: JsonApiError, result?: string): any
}
```

In order to create callback holding variable that implements that interface (see comments) you can write:

```js
const callback: HandlerCallback<Request, any> = (err?: JsonApiError, req?: Request, count?: any) => ({ err, req, count });

// Or

const callback2: HandlerCallback<Request> = (err?: JsonApiError, req?: Request) => ({ err, req });
```

Comment: Is the interface telling me I can create one of two functions?

Comment: @westandy so in the case you mentioned in comment your `R` will be `Request` type and your `C` will be `number`, Hope my edited answer can serve as a sufficient example for that.

Comment: I've tried this: `const cb: HandlerCallback<Request, any> = (err: JsonApiError, req: Request, count: any): any => ({
        err,
        req,
        count
      });` and TypeScript is saying No.  I'm very confused.

Comment: But this works:   `const cb: HandlerCallback<Request> = (err: JsonApiError, req: Request): any => ({
        err,
        req
      });`

Comment: @westandy When using this type of interface you don't need to manually set type for every callback argument or return type you can just `const cb: HandlerCallback<Request, any> = (err, req, count) => ({ err, req, count });`

Comment: My tsc does not like that either.  It's the C=`defined` part that seems impossible to create.

Comment: @westandy My bad, you actually need to specify argument types. The thing that you are missing is to make arguments optional. This will work: `const callback: HandlerCallback<Request, any> = (err?: JsonApiError, req?: Request, count?: any) => ({ err, req, count });`

Comment: Boom!  Write that up in the answer box and I'll give ya the Green check!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @westandy Here you go :)

Comment: Again, thank you so much for answering that, @Minwork